# How to keep 10 decimal in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, decimal

I want to create a 3*2 matrix, first column is the original number(large number), and I want to convert the original number into scientific notation format, a * 10^n, second column is used to store 'a', third column stores 'n'.

```
    install.package("formattable")
    library("formattable")

    x=-99999887310  #my input
    y_upper=10000 - x  #original number 1
    y_lower=-10000 - x   #original number 2
    y<-matrix(c(y_upper,y_lower),byrow=TRUE) #store original number into matrix y
    y<-cbind(y,floor(log10(abs(y[,1])) + 1) - 1) #2nd column
    y<-cbind(y,formattable(y[,1]/(10^(y[,2])),digit = 10, format = "f")) 
     #3rd column
    #output from above code
    #            [,1] [,2]     [,3]
    #[1,] 99999897310   10 9.999990
    #[2,] 99999877310   10 9.999988
    #Ideal output I want
     #            [,1] [,2]     [,3]
    #[1,] 99999897310   10 9.9999897310
    #[2,] 99999877310   10 9.9999877310
```

Note: I download a library called "formattable" and use one of the function "formattable", by default, it returns a vector which keeps 10 decimal, but when I put it back to the matrix, I lose the 10 decimal again.

Comment: Hi Frank, I've edited my code portion to make it reproducible. Someone can simply run my code now. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: `print(y, digits = 10)` ?

Comment: - rawr, this works!! thanks!